# Why is my action-listener not displaying the proper image when clicked?

Tags: java, arrays, image, swing, shuffle

I am currently in the middle of trying to code a matching game. I have created a 2-d array for `JButton` and `ImageIcon`. I have done a shuffling class name `Shuffle` this class shuffles the `ImageIcon`'s position in it's array. When starting the game without the base cards, the cards appear to be shuffled. But when I start the game with the base cards and incorporate the action listener, when you click on the card there is no image. If someone could help me figure out this problem it would be very appreciated.

Consider this code:

Method for the frame:

```
void game() {
        Shuffle shuffle = new Shuffle();
        shuffle.random2();
        ImageIcon base = new ImageIcon("images/BaseCard.png");
        int x = 60;
        int y = 20;
        JFrame frame = obj.frame();
        JLabel label = obj.label();
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cards[i].length; ++j) {
                cards[i][j] = obj.Comp(base);
                cards[i][j].addActionListener(new Clicked(i, j));
                cards[i][j].setBounds(x, y, 90, 126);
                y = y + 135;
                if (y >= 540) {
                    y = 20;
                    x = x + 120;
                }
                frame.add(cards[i][j]);
            }
        }

        frame.add(label);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is the Shuffle class:

```
class Shuffle {

    Matching obj = new Matching();
    String peach = "images/peach.png";
    String daisy = "images/Baby_daisy.png";
    String luigi = "images/Baby_Luigi.png";
    String waluigi = "images/Baby_Waluigi.png";
    String wario = "images/Baby_Wario.png";
    String bowser = "images/BabyBowser.png";
    String drybones = "images/DryBones.png";
    String shyguy = "images/ShyGuy.png";

    String[][] images = {
        {peach, daisy, luigi, waluigi},
        {wario, bowser, drybones, shyguy},
        {peach, daisy, luigi, waluigi},
        {wario, bowser, drybones, shyguy}
    };

    ImageIcon Icons[][] = new ImageIcon[4][4];

    void random2() {

        for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < images[i].length; j++) {
                int i1 = (int) (Math.random() * images.length);
                int j1 = (int) (Math.random() * images[i].length);

                String temp = images[i][j];
                images[i][j] = images[i1][j1];
                images[i1][j1] = temp;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < images[i].length; j++) {
                Icons[i][j] = new ImageIcon(images[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the Action Listener

```
class Clicked implements ActionListener {

    Shuffle shuffle = new Shuffle();
    Matching matching = new Matching();
    private int i;
    private int j;

    public Clicked(int i, int j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JToggleButton tBtn = (JToggleButton) e.getSource();
        if (tBtn.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("click");
            tBtn.setIcon(shuffle.Icons[i][j]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("not");
            tBtn.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/BaseCard.png"));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why not include a few more lines of code and post a [reprex] that could be run by someone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Clicked` class you're creating a new `Shuffle` instead of:

```
public Clicked(Shuffle shuffle) {
    this.shuffle = shuffle;
}
```

which would give you the previously created and shuffled "deck" of cards.  You also may want to look into just having the one `Clicked` and using it for all the cards, just watch out for any threading issues if you start changing your `Shuffle`.